# Edit Hidden Footer Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is the footer of code for my theme. I would like to Remove "Powered by WordPress" but i can not see the solution here, please help

```
<?php do_action( 'maxwell_before_footer' ); ?>

<div id="footer" class="footer-wrap">

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer container clearfix" role="contentinfo">

        <?php do_action( 'maxwell_footer_menu' ); ?>

        <div id="footer-text" class="site-info">
            <?php do_action( 'maxwell_footer_text' ); ?>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->

    </footer><!-- #colophon -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's right here: `<?php do_action( 'maxwell_footer_text' ); ?>`

Replace that with whatever you want in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You find the WordPress footer by commenting out each `do_action` method call in turn until the text goes away. After that you can grep the theme source to find the source method.

Answer (score 0):

//You can replace div or do_action according to your choice

```
<div id=”footer-text” class=”site-info”>
<?php do_action( ‘maxwell_footer_text’ ); ?>
</div>
```

//Or hide it by css

```
.site-info {
    display: none;
}
```